# TFS variables for connection string

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, tfs, connection-string, web-deployment

I have continous integration in tfs project. I want to replace connection string to my production db on release, but all the information on the web is confusing. I created `parameters.xml` with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
  <parameter name="connectionString" description="connectionString" defaultvalue="(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;InitialCatalog=BlogsPostsLocalDb;Integrated Security=true;" tags="">
    <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="What to write here?" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

In TFS, in my `App Deploy` task I can see `SetParameters File` option, so I suspect that I have to use that, but I don't understand how to tell it which parameter in `Web.config` belongs to the parameter in `parameters.xml`.

In my `Web.config` I need to replace static path with the one in `parameters.xml`. My `Web.config`:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;InitialCatalog=BlogsPostsLocalDb;Integrated Security=true;" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

EDIT:

I used a tool to create `parameters.xml` which now looks like this:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter name="ConnectionString" description="Description for ConnectionString" defaultvalue="__CONNECTIONSTRING__" tags="">
    <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ConnectionString']/@value" />
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

My `web.config`:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BlogsPostsTestDb;Integrated Security=True" />
  </appSettings>
```

And in my context I do this:

```
public BlogsPostsContext() : base(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]) { }
```

In TFS I set variable for relase

```
Name             | Value
ConnectionString | Data Source=WIN-7ADV5BGRBE3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BlogsPostsDb;Integrated Security=True
```

Unfortunately when I do a release and look inside `web.config` on my server I can only see `<add key="ConnectionString" value="__CONNECTIONSTRING__" />`
And the `parameters.xml`:

```
<parameters> 
    <parameter name="ConnectionString" description="Description for ConnectionString" defaultvalue="__CONNECTIONSTRING__" tags="">
    <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ConnectionString']/@value" />
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

MsBuild Arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

[image]

Comment: Which task did you use to replace the connection strings by variable? Can you share a screenshot for the settings of that task?

Comment: @MSFT I updated my question.

Comment: Can you expand the "File Transforms & Variable Subsitution Options" setting and then share the screenshot?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I updated the screenshot.

Comment: So you are using "XML variable substitution" option to replace the connection strings? The IIS Web Application Deployment tasks you use is preview version and very old, I cannot find it any more. Can you share the extension so that I can check it on my side? By the way, the extension has been deprecated and replaced by this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp, I recommend you to try with the new extension if possible.

Comment: How is it possible that I'm using old version? All I did was I created a tfs project from `*.visualstudio.com` and configured continous integration with these tasks, so that when I push new commit it automatically deploys. I do not use any extensions other than team explorer. Is my way of doing this deprecated?

Comment: Yes, check the link in my previous comments. It already mentioned that: "The Visual Studio Team Services accounts that are using the preview tasks wiz. IIS Web Application Deployment or SQL Server Database Deployment, should move to this extension."

Comment: Ok, thank you I will install it. Btw. I fixed the issue from my question. I don't need the `parameters.xml` file at all. All I had to to do was to add `connectionstring` inside `Web.Release.config`. Basically all that was required was written inside this file.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following articles about `parameters.xml` mislead me. It turns out that all I had to do to make it work was to follow instructions inside `Web.Release.Config`.

This is what I added inside `Web.config`:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BlogsPostsDb"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BlogsPostsTestDb;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And this is what I added inside `Web.Release.Config`:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BlogsPostsDb" 
         connectionString="Data Source=myServerInstance;Initial Catalog=BlogsPostsDb;User ID=*********;Password=******;" 
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now it makes sense. As long as the names match in both configs, they will be replaced. I also had to tell my context which connection string I want to use:

```
public BlogsPostsContext() : base("BlogsPostsDb") { }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `[project name].SetParameters.xml` file is generated when you build a web application project.

> This provides a set of parameter values to the `MSDeploy.exe` command.
>   You can update the values in this file and pass it to Web Deploy as a
>   command-line parameter when you deploy your web package.

Since  `SetParameters.xml` file is dynamically generated from your web application project file and any configuration files within your project.

You could also parameterize additional settings by adding a `parameters.xml` file to your project.  Below entry uses an XML Path Language (XPath) query to locate and parameterize the endpoint URL of the *ContactService Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)* service in the web.config file.

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="ContactService Service Endpoint Address"
             description="Specify the endpoint URL for the ContactService WCF 
                          service in the destination environment"
             defaultValue="http://localhost/ContactManagerService">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web.config"
                    match="/configuration/system.serviceModel/client
                           /endpoint[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IContactService']
                           /@address" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

The WPP also adds a corresponding entry to the SetParameters.xml file that gets generated alongside the deployment package.

```
<parameters>
  ...  
  <setParameter 
    name="ContactService Service Endpoint Address" 
    value="http://localhost/ContactManagerService" />
  ...
</parameters>
```

For how to tell it which parameter in Web.config belongs to the parameter in parameters.xml, you need to use match entry to do this. More detail info please refer this tutorial: [Configuring Parameters for Web Package Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/configuring-parameters-for-web-package-deployment)

Comment: I used a program to generate the file. The problem is that linking variables from tfs to my config doesn't work. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I am using ASP.Net and IIS application in visual studio i created a configuration for example Test for any cpu then i publish a IIS file called test.pubxml (right click on project click publish), That file will contain the connection string from your web.config file , Then you right-click on the file you have created (test.pubxml) and select  **add web-transform file** add the following iy you want to transform the connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="test" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;InitialCatalog=BlogsPostsLocalDb;Integrated Security=true;" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now you have a file that will do the exact same things as parameters.xml file.

In your build defition add the following to ms arguments

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=test.pubxml;Configuration=Test;

That will build a .zip package,

**In your Release Definition**

In your deploy step, Add the following to your Web Deploy Parameter File input

> Path/Path/test.SetParameters.xml

That Will deploy the website with transformed connection string.

I know its a lot but you can follow this blog its really helpfull [Colin](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/webdeploy-configs-and-web-release-management)